# GridSearchCV for number of neurons

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, grid-search

I am trying to learn by myself how to grid-search number of neurons in a basic multi-layered neural networks. I am using GridSearchCV and KerasClasifier of Python as well as Keras. The code below works for other data sets very well but I could not make it work for Iris dataset for some reasons and I cannot find it why, I am missing out something here. The result I get is:

`Best: 0.000000 using {'n_neurons': 3}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'n_neurons': 3}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'n_neurons': 5}`

```
from pandas import read_csv

import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

dataframe=read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
dataset=dataframe.values
X=dataset[:,0:4].astype(float)
Y=dataset[:,4]

seed=7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

#encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)

#one-hot encoding
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

#scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

def create_model(n_neurons=1):
    #create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(n_neurons, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu')) # hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax')) # output layer
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=10, initial_epoch=0, verbose=0)
# define the grid search parameters
neurons=[3, 5]

#this does 3-fold classification. One can change k. 
param_grid = dict(n_neurons=neurons)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, dummy_y)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

For the purpose of illustration and computational efficiency I search only for two values.  I sincerely apologize for asking such a simple question. I am new to Python, switched from R, by the way because I realized that Deep Learning community is using python.

Comment: Didn't look at your code but GridSearch for DL, really? Bad idea IMO. The more neurons you put(until you hit the bottleneck), the better things will be(theoretically) but that doesn't mean your architecture is also good

Comment: I totally understand you. I already run that model with number of neurons of 8 and get a good accuracy. Since I am new to Python, I just want to perform some artificial analysis if possible.

Comment: (1) I'm not going with the first comment. It might be true in regards to training-loss (and good fitting-params) but using CV it's a viable approach (where simpler schemes can be better)! (2) The code is not reproducible as at least the data is missing (3) What other datasets work? How did you deduce they are working? What's the difference between this one and the others? Iris is actually one of the most simple datasets and perfect score is possible (4) Make sure you check score is doing what it's supposed to do (score vs. loss;maybe use some explicit scorer function)(5)Check preds of best res

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha, this is probably the funniest thing I ever experienced on Stack Overflow :) Check:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
```

and you should see different behavior. The reason why your model get a perfect score (in terms of `cross_entropy` having `0` is equivalent to best model possible) is that you haven't shuffled your data and because `Iris` consist of three balanced classes each of your feed had a single class like a target:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (first fold ends here) 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (second fold ends here)2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2]
```

Such problems are really easy to be solved by every model - so that's why you've got a perfect match.

Try to shuffle your data before - this should result in an expected behavior.

Comment: oh lol yes you are right! Geeezzz haha I hate myself now. You are absolutely right. I missed that point, instead totally focusing on method itself. I guess I was confused with model.fit shuffling by default. Thank you! And I am sorry!

Comment: you got it, mate!